# Как апгрейдить QTcpSocket на QWebSocket

Tags: c++, qt5, websocket

Проект на C++ Qt5. По замыслу на http-сайте (QTcpServer, QTcpSocket) нужно установить постоянное соединение для онлайн-чата. Хочу использовать родные вебсокеты Qt, но не могу понять как мне следует "переключить" соединение на вебсокет после стандартных http-операций (хендшейка). У QWebSocket имеется конструктор, который принимает указатель на QTcpSocket, но к моему удивлению он приватный. Пробовал гуглить - тишина, будто я третий человек на планете, который задался вопросом (предыдущие двое не получили ответ).

Comment: Если вы сами обрабатываете протокол HTTP, то что мешает сделать то же самое с протоколом веб-сокетов?

Comment: А вообще, обратите внимание на класс QWebSocketServer

Comment: @PavelMayorov я пробовал. Однако, протокол вебсокетов далеко не пара HTTP. Прочитал половину англоязычной спецификации, что-то даже понял, но отчаялся, так как на самопальную реализацию уйдет явно не пара дней. Затем узнал, что вебсокеты есть в Qt. И вот думаю как это по-человечи организовать.

Comment: вообще-то, если не учитывать фазу установки соединения (которую вы, как пишете, уже сделали) - то веб-сокеты являются очень простым протоколом, который пишется максимум за час

Comment: @PavelMayorov споры здесь не уместны (тем более, что одному легко, другому просто). Если вы судите о сложности по статье на Хабре от ~2009 года (как я сам изначально судил), ошибаетесь. Официальная спецификация протокола опубликована в 2011 году и там всё гораздо замудреннее, чем в старой русскоязычной статье.

Comment: я сужу о сложности исключительно на основе своего опыта, а не на основе статей с Хабра